# Python program that extracts most frequently found names from .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, extract, names

I have created a program that generates 5000 random names, ssn, city, address, and email and stored them in fakeprofile.csv file. I am trying to extract the most common names from the file. I was able to get the program to work syntactically but fail to extract frequent names.
Here's the code:

```
import re
import statistics
file_open = open('fakeprofile.csv').read()
frequent_names = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', file_open)
print(frequent_names)
```

Sample in the file:

```
Alicia Walters 419-52-4141 Yorkstad 66616 Schultz Extensions Suite 225
Reynoldsmouth, VA 72465 stevenserin@stein.biz
Nicole Duffy 212-38-9009 West Timothy 51077 Phillips Ports Apt. 314
Hubbardville, IN 06723 kaitlinthomas@bennett-carter.com
Stephanie Lewis 442-20-1279 Jacquelineshire 650 Gutierrez Forge Apt. 839
West Christianbury, TN 13654 ukelley@gmail.com
Michael Harris 108-81-3733 East Toddberg 14387 Douglas Mission Suite 038
Garciaview, WI 58624 kshields@yahoo.com
Aaron Moreno 171-30-7715 Port Taraburgh 56672 Wagner Path
Lake Christopher, VA 37884 lucasscott@nguyen.info
Alicia Zimmerman 286-88-9507 Barberstad 5365 Heath Extensions Apt. 731
South Randyburgh, NJ 79367 daniellewebb@yahoo.com
Brittney Mcmillan 334-44-0321 Lisahaven PSC 3856, Box 2428
APO AE 03215 kevin95@hotmail.com
Amanda Perkins 327-31-6610 Perryville 8750 Hurst Harbor Apt. 929
```

Sample output:

```
', 'Lake', 'Brianna', 'P', 'A', 'Michael', 'Smith', 'Harveymouth', 'Patricia', 'Tunnel', 'West', 'William', 'G', 'A', 'Charles', 'Perkins', 'Lake', 'Marie', 'Lisa', 'Overpass', 'Suite', 'Kennedymouth', 'C', 'A', 'Barbara', 'Perez', 'Billyshire', 'Joshua', 'Village', 'Cindymouth', 'W', 'I', 'Curtis', 'Simmons', 'North', 'Mitchellport', 'Gordon', 'Crest', 'Suite', 'Jacksonburgh', 'C', 'O', 'Cameron', 'Berg', 'South', 'Dean', 'Christina', 'Coves', 'Williamton', 'T', 'N', 'Maria', 'Williams', 'North', 'Judith', 'Carson', 'Overpass', 'Apt', 'West', 'Amandastad', 'N', 'M', 'Hannah', 'Dennis', 'Rodriguezmouth', 'P', 'S', 'C', 'Box', 'A', 'P', 'O', 'A', 'E', 'Laura', 'Richardson', 'Lake', 'Kayla', 'Johnson', 'Place', 'Suite', 'Port', 'Jennifermouth', 'N', 'H', 'John', 'Lawson', 'Hintonhaven', 'Thomas', 'Via', 'Mossport', 'N', 'J', 'Jennifer', 'Hill', 'East', 'Phillip', 'P', 'S', 'C', 'Box', 'A', 'P', 'O', 'A', 'E', 'Cody', 'Jackson', 'Lake', 'Jessicamouth', 'Snyder', 'Ways', 'Apt', 'New', 'Stacey', 'M', 'E', 'Ryan', 'Friedman', 'Shahburgh', 'Jerry', 'Pike', 'Suite', 'Toddfort', 'N', 'V', 'Kathleen', 'Fox', 'Ferrellmouth', 'P', 'S', 'C', 'Box', 'A', 'P', 'O', 'A', 'P', 'Michael', 'Thompson', 'Port', 'Jessica', 'Boone', 'Spurs', 'Suite', 'Port', 'Ashleyland', 'C', 'O', 'Christopher', 'Marsh', 'North', 'Catherine', 'Scott', 'Trail', 'Apt', 'Baileyburgh', 'F', 'L', 'Richard', 'Rangel', 'New', 'Anna', 'Ray', 'Drive', 'Apt', 'Nunezland', 'I', 'A', 'Connor', 'Stanton', 'Troyshire', 'Rodgers', 'Hill', 'West', 'Annmouth', 'N', 'H', 'James', 'Medina',
```

My issue here is being unable to extract most **frequently** found first names as well as avoiding those capital letters. Instead, I have extracted all names (including the unnecessary capital letters) and the one seen above is a small sample of all names extracted. I noticed that the first names are always on the odd rows in the output, and I am trying to capture the most frequent first names in those odd rows.

The fakeprofile.csv file was created by this program:

```
import csv
import faker
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
name = fake.name(); print(name)
ssn = fake.ssn(); print(ssn)
city = fake.city(); print(city)
address = fake.address(); print(address)
email = fake.email(); print(email)
profile = fake.simple_profile()
for i,j in profile.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(i,j))
print('Name: {}, SSN: {}, City: {}, Address: {}, Email: {}'.format(name,ssn,city,address,email))
with open('fakeprofile.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0,5001):
        print(f'{fake.name()} {fake.ssn()} {fake.city()} {fake.address()} {fake.email()}', file=f)
```

Comment: Are you asking a question about the regexp? Can you show a sample of your file? to sort the counter by occurrence you can do [(k,v) for k,v in sorted(count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]

Comment: No, I updated post with sample info from the.csv file.

Comment: Does the data follow a pattern? That input file you shared does not seem like valid CSV.

Comment: The data has a (name,ssn,city,address,email) format that is generated by another program and stored in the fakeprofile.csv file.

Comment: @Pkd It doesn’t look like it’s respecting the format, then, I barely see any commas. Can you be more specific, what is the **exact** format?

Comment: Sorry, I meant no commas but copied the code from a method that uses commas. The actual format (ignoring the syntax in the method) is print(f'{fake.name()} {fake.ssn()} {fake.city()} {fake.address()} {fake.email()}', file=f) where there is a space between each credential.

Comment: @Pkd Are you allowed to modify the data generator program? Some changes in design would go a long way. Why aren’t you using the csv module, for example? Using spaces to separate this kind of data is just a bad idea, I see no reason not to go for safer and more practical alternatives.

Comment: Yes, though I had this program made from YouTube, feel free to optimize it. The results should be the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you want?

```py
import collections, re

# Read in all lines into a list
with open('fakeprofile.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# Throw out every other line
lines = [line for i, line in enumerate(lines) if i%2 == 0]
# Keep only first word of each line
names = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
# Find most common names
n = 3
frequent_names = collections.Counter(names).most_common(n)
# Display most common names
for name, count in frequent_names:
    print(name, count)
```

To do the counting it uses [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) together with its [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method.

Comment: The code displays names such as Apt, Suite, and West. What I am looking for is the first word (first name) of every odd row.

Comment: That is not at all what your question states??

Comment: Ah, I need to specify the names I am looking for. In the output above, you'll notice every odd row (1,3,5,7,etc) has a first name, and I'm looking for the most common first names from those odd rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think It would have been better if you use pandas library, for the CSV manipulation (collecting the desire information ), and then apply python collection like counter(df ['name'] ) into it, or else could you give us more information about the CSV file.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

So the main problem you have is that you use a regexp that will capture every letter. 
You are interested in the first world in the odd line.

you can do something on those lines:

```
# either use a dict to count or a list to transform as counter.
dico_count = {}
with open('fakeprofile.csv') as file_open:  # use of context manager

    line_number = 1
    for line in file_open: #iterates all the lines

        if line_number % 2 != 0 : # odd line

            spt = line.strip().split()
            dico_count[spt[0]] = dico_count.get(spt[0], 0) + 1

frequent_name_counter = [(k,v) for k,v in sorted(dico_count.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
```

Comment: This file does not work for me. The code I posted above works with the code that created the fakeprofile.csv file, where I updated the post with.